# Mac Installation crashed

Tags: mac, installation, iso-image

My Mac gets stuck on startup. It loads and gets near the end of the bar and then freezes. I need to make a bootable Mac ISO. I've been trying to use TransMac to make bootable recvory usb drives from DMGs that I downloaded online but they do not show up on Mac's boot screen. If possible, can someone send me a link to a bootable mac iso file?

Comment: Depends on what Mac it is as to whether it will boot from USB or DVD. Your question needs more detail.

Comment: Mac 2010 w/ Yosemite. I was trying upgrade to El Capitan. I need to boot from USB

Comment: If it has, or had, a SuperDrive, it's going to be easier to get it to boot from DVD. Alternatively, cmd/r at the chimes & use Internet Recovery.